# iOS - VC already presenting (null), on a presented VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm having an issue that goes `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x15ce86c10>  on <MyProject.MyViewController: 0x15ce7fe80> which is already presenting (null)`

I've read several answer that indicates the issue is cause because `MyViewController` is already presenting something (and it must be dismissed before presenting another thing).

In my particular case, `MyViewController` **is not presenting anything, but it is being presented by** `MyRootViewController`

In other words, it goes like this: `MyRootViewController` --> presents --> `MyViewController` --> presents --> `UIAlertController`.

Is, the fact that `MyViewController` is presented by `MyRootViewController`, the reason I cannot present `UIAlertController`?

**Edit:**

Code is pretty large, the calls are performed like this:

```
// MyRootViewController
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("go_to_MyViewController", sender: self)  // It is a "Present Modally" segue

// MyViewController
self.presentViewController(myAlertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: add your code please. how do present this controller and where?